# How to get dotted leads in ToC using book class

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using the book class and I need dotted leads in the ToC for chapters. tocloft package doesn't seem to work. I am using TexShop.

I currently have this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{mainmatter}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection}
\section{section 2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{mainmatter}
\end{document}
```

The sections have dotted leads but the chapters do not.

I have tried including the `tocloft` package but couldn't get it to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{mainmatter}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection}
\section{section 2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{mainmatter}
\end{document}
```

I get an error saying 'Undefined Control Sequence'

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded                         format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 entering extended mode
(./testingTOC.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo))
(./tocloft.sty (./stdclsdv.sty)) (./testingTOC.aux) (./testingTOC.toc
./testingTOC.toc:1: Undefined control sequence.
\cftchapleader ->\cftdotfill 
                         {\cftdotsep }
l.1 ...line {chapter}{\numberline {1}Chapter 1}{1}

? ]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please provide a minimal working example that shows your problem in as little code as possible?

Comment: please add it to your question completely (you accidentally sent the comment, I guess) and use the {} button to make it a code block

Comment: for me your MWE works (and produces the desired output), if I insert the tocloft package and the renewcommand.

Comment: I copied and pasted your edited version - still working perfectly. Could you post the whole error message?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up getting to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{mainmatter}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection}
\section{section 2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\end{mainmatter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without `tocloft`, by redefinition of `\l@chapter`, adding the `\@dottedtocline` command inside and adjusting the horizontal skips.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{showframe}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
  \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
  \begingroup
  \parindent\z@ 
  \rightskip\@pnumwidth
  \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
  \leavevmode  
  \@dottedtocline{0}{0em}{1.5em}{%
    \bfseries #1}{\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}}%
  \penalty\@highpenalty
  \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{mainmatter}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection}
\section{section 2}

\chapter{Chapter 2}

\chapter{Chapter with a very long title that is completely useless but we will try it }
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection}

\end{mainmatter}
\end{document}
```

[image]