# Leading dots near chapters in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a question, how to make leading dots in a table of content near chapters? I searched then internet and found only solutions how to add leading dots to sections, but not for chapters. I have tried to use:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapdotsep}}
```

but its not working for me.

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
\documentclass{report}[12pt]
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I have added a example.

Comment: does this help: [How to get dotted leads in ToC using book class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303446) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You MWE has only 3 letters too much: The command uses `chap` instead of `chapter`

```
\documentclass{report}[12pt]
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used it with `chap` only, but this didn't worked for me. But now, when I copy cat your solution, it worked. Maybe I miss spelled something. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have I understood well your question?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}% 
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Leaf}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: To demonstrate this you probably should start a chapter rather than just a section (or better use `\chapter{Foo}\section{Bar}` to have both a chapter and section in ToC).  The `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` here are unecessary, as is loading [`babel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel).

Comment: You use \section{leaf}. I want that would be \chapter{leaf}