# How to add dots to the chapters?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, koma-script

[image]

How can I add dots like that in the picture to the chapters in my toc?

This is my document class. I have mostly been reading on here that people solve this problem my using `memoir`. Is there another (easy) way?

`\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrreprt}`

Comment: This question may help: [How to get dotted leads in ToC using book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303446)

Comment: If you weren't using `scrreprt` I would recommend the `tocloft` package (or of course the `memoir` class;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use option `toc=chapterentrywithdots`:

```latex
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false,headings=optiontoheadandtoc,
  toc=chapterentrywithdots% <- added
]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{document}
```

or `\RedeclareSectionCommand` with option `toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill`

```latex
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false,headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrreprt}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  toclinefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{chapter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{document}
```

or `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` with option `linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill`:

```latex
\documentclass[sfdefaults,headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrreprt}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill
]{tocline}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Introduction}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Remark:

For KOMA-Script version 3.39 or newer class option `sfdefaults=false` replaces the deprecated and undocumented option `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles`.