# How to force adding dotted line on chapter without ruin the chapter fontsize

Tags: page-numbering, book-class

i found related problems to this, [See duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303456/221368).
but, when i tried to use this codes, this ruined my chapter fontsize like this:
[see picture](https://ibb.co/8BQLJH3)

i have setting the fontsize of the chapter using `\titleformat`. So, i've changed the chapter fontsize to 12pt. And after using code from duplicate link, my fontsize was ruin and getting bigger.

This is my codes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}  %MY ATTEMPT HERE
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\bfseries\centering}
    {\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}


\begin{document}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter %

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\include{cover1}
\include{cover2}
\linespread{1}
\tableofcontents %TABLE OF CONTENTS
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter %

\end{document}
```

Btw, i'm using cmd: `\chapter*{...}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}`. To create chapter title. Not shown on my code cz it includes on another file. I split my main file into some parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem is but perhaps using the `titles` option to `tocloft` solves it.

```
% chapterdotsprob.tex SE 555536

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=4cm, outer=3cm, top=4cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\linespread{1.5}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}  %MY ATTEMPT HERE
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\bfseries\centering}
    {\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}
%\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}  %MY ATTEMPT HERE

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{DAFTAR ISI}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{DAFTAR TABEL}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}


\begin{document}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter %

\pagestyle{fancy}   
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\include{cover1}
\include{cover2}
\linespread{1}
\tableofcontents %TABLE OF CONTENTS
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter %

\chapter{One}
Some text
\chapter{Two}
More text.

\end{document}
```

The `titles` option makes the titles of the ToC, etc., look like those of the chapters in the document.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for the help.